Forces on leaning sticks
I am currently going through Morin's Introduction to Classical Mechanics book)
Here's the problem:

The solution claims that 
How did they derive M1/Mr = tan theta ? Is it a result of Newton's 3rd law?

Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead.


How did they derive $\frac {M_l} {M_r} = \tan \theta$ ?

The question tells us that

The sticks have the same mass density per unit length

so their masses are proportional to their lengths. And the ratio of the lengths of the two sticks is $\tan \theta$.
